# ProgressBar no se activa Winform

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo en mi programa un `proguesBarr`definida como `visible=false` quiero que se muestre y active al hacer clic en crear nueva partida, este botón lo que hace es inicializar todos los datos del usuario en la base de datos, con los datos por defecto necesarios lo que tarda entre 2 y 3 segundos. He probado haciéndolo en un `timer`normal;

```
    public void InsertarPartida()
    {
        idPartida = maxID();
        String nombre = txtNuevaPartida.Text;
        fb.lblNombre = nombre;
        if (txtNuevaPartida.Text != "")
        {   
            progressBar1.Visible = true;
            timerBarraProgreso.Start();

            using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(conectionString))...


            cargarDatosPorDefecto();
            tutorial = true;
            abrirInicioJuego();
        }
        else
        {
            mens.mensaje = "Introduce un nombre para poder dirigirnos a ti :)";
            mens.ShowDialog(this);
        }
    }
```

Aqui el codigo del `timer` que lanzo en el método;

```
    private void timerBarraProgreso_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.progressBar1.Increment(10);
    }
```

Otra opción que he probado es lanzar el timer de la barra de progreso en un Hilo secundario;

```
    private void lanzarHiloProgressBar()
    {
        this.progressBar1.Visible = true;
        this.progressBar1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        Thread t = new Thread(timerBarraProgreso.Start);
        t.Start();
    }
```

Comment: A ver si entendi, lo que quieres es evitar el retroceso de los 2 o 4 segundos cuando cargar los datos de la db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas crear un método asíncrono, que se va a encargar de cargar los datos, algo así:

```
// en este método cargas tus datos
private async Task<List<tipodedatoquecargas>> CargaDatosPorDefecto()
{
     return await Task.Run(() => {
          // creas una lista donde cargaras tus dagos
          var listacargada = new List<tipodddatoquecargas>();
          // aquí va el código donde cargas tus datos
         return listacargada; // regresas la lista ya llena de datos
     };
}
```

Luego, insertarpartida la haces también async:

```
private async Task CargarPartida()
{
    // para cargar los datos haces:
    var datos = await CargaDatosPorDefecto();
    // y haces lo que quieras hacer con los datos, no hagas llamadas a la UI aquí
}
```

Y en el evento donde se hace la llamada  a CargarPartida (Load o Click de un botón), lo cambias así:

```
private async void boton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.progressBar1.Visible = true;
    await CargaPartida();
    this.progressBar1.Visible = false;
}
```

A la barra de progreso la configuras para que sea "marquee". Si de verdad necesitas que la barra de progreso vaya avanzando, vas a tener que cambiar mas lógica.

No entiendo porque no se recomienda el uso de Tasks (async/await) y se recomiendan cosas como thread y demás opciones anticuadas

Answer (score 3):

No necesitas un timer para que el progress refleje trabajo, este control tiene el modo marquee 
asigna la propiedad

```
 progressbar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
```

de esta forma cuando inicias la consulta se vera el progress moviendose a la speed que definas mientas se consulta la db, sin necesidad de ningun timer

[Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.style(v=vs.110).aspx)

[ProgressBar.MarqueeAnimationSpeed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.marqueeanimationspeed(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que he entendido el problema que tienes es que mientras se ejecuta la consulta, el UI se queda congelado. Quieres mostrar una barra de progreso pero no se actualiza, se queda congelada igual que el resto del UI mientras no termina la consulta.

Eso es porque haces ambas cosas en el thread del UI, no se arreglará con un timer porque sigues dentro del thread del UI.

Yo siempre que tengo que mostrar progreso con una barra de progreso u otra cosa, uso el BackgroundWorker. El BackgroundWorker genera un thread aparte del UI y no congela el UI. Sin embargo ten cuidado porque no se puede actualizar el UI desde el thread del worker (es un thread separado y te dará un petardazo).

Échale un vistazo a algún tutorial del BackgroundWorker y veras que es muy sencillo de usar: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Lo siento con el tema de la semana santa deje un poco de lado este tema, la solución que le di fue algo parecido a lo que mencionas @Luis;

```
    public async void InsertarPartida()
    {
        idPartida = maxID();
        String nombre = txtNuevaPartida.Text;
        fb.lblNombre = nombre;

        if (txtNuevaPartida.Text != "")
        {
            progressBar1.Visible = true;
            timerBarraProgreso.Start();
            //progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
            //Se lanza una tarea para intentar activar la puta barra de progreso

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {      
            using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(conectionString))...
            cargarDatosPorDefecto();
            tutorial = true;
            });
            abrirInicioJuego();

        }
        else
        {
            mens.mensaje = "Introduce un nombre para poder dirigirnos a ti :)";
            mens.ShowDialog(this);
        }
    }
```

Lo que hice fue introducir las lineas de código que requerían de tiempo para ejecutarse en una tarea para que no bloqueen el hilo principal y pueda mostrarse el `progressBar`, como dice @Luis lo que intente hacer de `thread`es algo anticuado.

Comment: Solo una pequeña observación, se recomienda que los métodos asíncronos regresen "Task" cuando no van a regresar nada y "async void" se utiliza para cuando quieres que un método manejador de eventos sea asíncrono, por ejemplo, el método que maneje el evento click de un botón, debe ser "private async void NombreMetodo(...", pero un método que no sea manejador de evento y no regrese nada debe ser "private async Task NombreMétodo(". https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: Vale, no lo había contemplado, gracias.